# Is it possible to manipulate the date this PHP code outputs?

Tags: php, date

```
<?php echo invoice_due_date($invoice); ?>
```

The above code outputs a date that is formatted as **dd/mm/yyyy**.  I am looking for a way to take that date and then add or remove x amount of days from it and then print the result.  I'm a novice when it comes to PHP so everything I have tried has failed.  Thanks in advance!

Also, this code snippet is from a no longer supported project called "myclientbase" if it helps.

Comment: [Yes, it is possible.](http://php.net/class.datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strtotime](http://ch2.php.net/strtotime) can translate the date to a time value (although you'd have to replace the slashes with dashes) and in the same operation add days:

```
strtotime(str_replace('/','-',invoice_due_date($invoice)) . ' + 1 day')
```

[date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) can be used to format the date back to a suitable notation.

Comment: `$invoice_change = strtotime(invoice_due_date($invoice) . '+30 days');
echo date ("m/d/y", $invoice_change);`

Ultimately worked for me.  Thanks for the help!  I'll explore the other option provided as well.

Answer (score 3):

PHP5 has a nice class called [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

You can initialize it from a string like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', invoice_due_date($invoice));
```

Then, since PHP 5.3.0 this class has a method to add time amounts:

```
$date->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));
```

This adds 10 days to your date. See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php.

Comment: Thanks for the direction!  I'll try this and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateTime::add function.  A full explanation and examples can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

```
$invoice->add(new DateInterval('P20D'));
```

This would add 20 days to the invoice date.  You can simply run this before echoing out your `$invoice` variable.